# Handling server redirection with traefik

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I have a http server running in a docker. Accessing the server at `/` redirects it to `/web`. This works fine locally. I have setup traefik to connect to the docker through `xxxxxxx.com` domain. However, this results in  a `404 page not found` but when I try `xxxxxxxx.com/web` it works. How does traefik handle this kind of redirects? Thanks in advance.
Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    image: odoo:10.0
    labels:
      - traefik.backend=web
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:portal.sironirestaurant.com
      - traefik.docker.network=proxy
      - traefik.port=8069
    networks:
      - internal
      - proxy
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8069:8069
    volumes:
      - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:9.4
    networks:
      - internal
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=false
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
      - POSTGRES_USER=xxxxxx          
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
      - odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
volumes:
  odoo-web-data:
  odoo-db-data:
```

Comment: could you give your docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile(s) content ?

Comment: @jmny I've improved the question